# Is there a way for NetBeans to automatically create brackets in a separate line?

Tags: java, ide, netbeans, brackets

When I create a new class for instance, I get this:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package helloworld;

/**
 *
 * @author Sergio
 */
public class WordManipulations{        
}
```

I **hate** it when brackets are placed this way. Is there a way to make it create things like this:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package helloworld;

/**
 *
 * @author Sergio
 */
public class WordManipulations 
{

}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? :S

Comment: hehe  The funny thing is that I have that style ( braces in a new line ) used in Java. The same way I hate C# using the former ( opening brace in the same line )  I think every language should adhere to the convention used by the core.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Simply follow these steps:

1. Navigate to `Tools -> Options -> Editor`
2. Navigate to `Editor -> Formatting`
3. Select the following

   - Language: Java
   - Category: Braces
4. In "Class Declaration, Method Declaration, etc."

   - Braces Placement: New Line

Comment: Wow so incredibly simple. Netbeans is really impressive.

Comment: Unfortunately this is currently broken (for C/C++ and PHP at least) in Netbeans 6.8 :(

Answer (score 2):

Also there's the JIndent plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans go to **Tools** > **Options**. Then select the **Formatting** tab and select **Java** under the language drop down.

There are now several options to change the formatting the way you like it.